# Check if other user is granted than the active one

Tags: symfony, authorization

We have some frontend logic that uses voters to check whether users can show documents. That same logic should be applied in the backend, the difference is that over there an admin user is the active one in the `TokenStorage`.

```
if (false === $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('show', $document)) {
   continue;
}
```

The same voters should be used, but with another user object (the owner of the document). Could not find any documentation on temporarily changing the authenticated user for the voters.

Although [the authorization docs mention `setToken`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authorization.html), I can not imagine that overwriting the token would be the way to go. So, is there a Symfony service we can use to apply the voting on our own user? One that is not currently active in the `TokenStorage` (yet)?

Comment: You can show the Voter source code, please?

Answer (score 3):

For `RoleVoter` decendents you can do it exchanging the token stored and restoring it back after check the permissions:

```
$tokenStorage = $this->get('security.token_storage');
$authorizationChecker = $this->get('security.authorization_checker');

// gets the user owner of the document
$owner = $document->getOwner();

// create new token for owner user/roles
$ownerToken = new AnonymousToken(null, $owner, $owner->getRoles());

// save current token to restore later
$prevToken = $tokenStorage->getToken();

// change the current token
$tokenStorage->setToken($ownerToken);

// checking now the owner roles
if ($authorizationChecker->isGranted('show', $document)) {
    // ...
}

// restore the previous token
$tokenStorage->setToken($prevToken);
```

These changes only affect the access decision in this moment. For reusability you can create a new AuthorizationChecker/Service to use the user instance as 3rd argument of `isGranted` method, something like this:

```
$user = $document->getOwner();

if ($this->get('my_authorization_checker')->isGranted('show', $document, $user)) {
    // ...
}
```

this method will check first if the user is provided or not, if so changes the token, else do nothing and checks the logged user.

Comment: I find it weird that checking authorization based by passing a `UserInterface` object isn't supported directly. What would be an argument  against?

Answer (score 1):

Try to make another authorizationChecker service

```
<service id="app.token_storage" class="Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage" />

<service id="app.authorization_checker" class="Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker">
      <argument type="service" id="app.token_storage"/>
      <argument type="service" id="security.authentication.manager"/>
      <argument type="service" id="security.access.decision_manager"/>
      <argument>false</argument>
</service>
```

And then in controller

```
$this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($yourTokenToBeChecked);
$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('show', $document);
```

Comment: This will also overwrite the token for the scope of the request, so the code snippet you mention could also be applied directly. So I think there isn't any other way so you don't have to "revert" the active token yourself?

Comment: It will not overwrite the token of the request. By defining `app.token_storage` you are creating another score, and no matter what you will put in it, a standart `security.token_storage` will still hold a token from the request.  You will have two token_storages and two authorization_checkers, each it's checking own storage.